# Find limit $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1-e^{-\frac{x}{n^{\gamma}}})^n$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $x>0$ and $\gamma<0$. 
Find limit $$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1-e^{-\frac{x}{n^{\gamma}}}\right)^n.$$

---

My try with L'Hôpital's rule gave me $1$. Is it right answer?

Comment: You should get $1$ as the final answer.

Comment: O, yeh! I've changed.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how did you use L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @Demosthene $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(1-e^{-\frac{x}{n^{\gamma}}}\right)^n = \lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln\left(1-e^{-xt^{\gamma}}\right)}{t}$.

Comment: @NikitaEvseev Oh, very nice :)